# Send extra parameters in an order with Avangate IPN

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, website-payment-pro

I want to integrate Avangate payment and as they have very poor information about how to do that I ask if anybody had implemented this.
I know that I put on my website a link to avangate like this:

```
https://secure.avangate.com/order/checkout.php?ORDERSTYLE=nLW0oJXfq34=&amp;PRODS=xxx3299&QTY=1
```

but somehow I need to know when payment is done by whom?
Any help will be very much appreciated.
[I understood that avangate is very much like e-payment ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the IPN notification.

IPN provides an automatic notification to be sent for authorized , authenticated and completed orders from Avangate’s online payment system. This notification method allows you to automatically receive the order data for future processing in your own order management systems.

The order information is sent as an HTTP POST.

You can find more details here: https://secure.avangate.com/cpanel/help.php?topic=api#Instant%20Payment%20Notification

If further information is required, please drop us a line at supportplus@avangate.com and we`ll be more than happy to assist.

Thank you,

Avangate Support

Comment: There are no working code examples for Instant Payment notifications. Do you plan to create them? Because this API is, to say the least, non-intuitive/